# Jest not recognizing mdx files

Tags: storybook, ts-jest, angular-storybook, storyshots

I have configured storybooks(6.1.14) for angular (11), I am currently importing mdx file into CSF(.stories.ts). Stories are compiling fine but when I run jest (for snapshot testing), it throws error

```
Cannot find module './SampleComponent.mdx' or its corresponding type declarations.
```